# в Post-запросе пустой объект

Tags: node.js, mvc, express

На node.js + express пишу форму входа. Дело в том, что get-запрос работает корректно, а post-запрос содержит в себе undefined. Использую примитивную форму: перехожу на роутер,

```
app.use("/", testRouter);
```

в котором код post-запроса (даже не использую контроллер ибо даже так не работает), и хочу взять данные req.body.id (т. к. в форме только поле id) и получается что req.body.id = undefined, даже req.body = undefined.

```
router.post("/test/submit", jsonParser, async function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body.id); // === undefined
});
```

что может быть за проблема?

Comment: Проблема может быть в отсутствии bodyParser middleware который десериализует данные из HTTP POST запроса в объекты JavaScript

Comment: app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

Comment: А код самой формы на клиенте какой?

Comment: уже нашла ошибку, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была вот в чем:
вместо:

```
app.set(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
```

это:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
```